# How to get all validation regular expressions for a model field?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to get all regular expressions (validators) corresponding to a model field to pass them to javascript (to validate on a client side).

However I can take all validators, but validators don't have regex field in **validator.__dict__**:

```
# from django.core.validators, URLValidator
class URLValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'  # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
        r'localhost|'  # localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'  # ...or ipv4
        r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'  # ...or ipv6
        r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
    message = _('Enter a valid URL.')

    def __call__(self, value):
        ... # and so on
```

The code trying to collect the regular expressions for models.URLField:

```
def get_regexes( model_obj, name ):
    field = model_obj._meta.get_field_by_name( name )[ 0 ]  

    # A list of all validators  
    validators = field.validators

    # Each validator can have attrs: 'regex', or '<some>_regex'

    for valid in validators:
        print "# valid={0}".format( valid ) # the dict has not regex field
        print "# valid_dict={0}".format( valid.__dict__ ) # the dict has not regex field

        obj_fields = valid.__dict__

        regexes = []

        if 'regex' in obj_fields:
            regexes.append( obj_fields.regex )

        # check if there are another regexes

        for key, val in obj_fields.iteritems():
            if '_regex' in key:
                regexes.append( obj_fields[ key ] )

    return regexes

print get_regexes( User, 'url' )
```

'url is a usual URLField in User model class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True) # Отчество

    url = models.URLField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

So, my code outputs:

```
# valid=<django.core.validators.URLValidator object at 0x0202AB70>
# valid_dict={}
# valid=<django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator object at 0x02158670>
# valid_dict={'limit_value': 200}
```

I see the validator objects but I can't realize where is the attribute regex (which is in the code of URLValidator).

Comment: `URLValidator` has a `regex` field on 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering to writer server-side code to do this? If you want to validate URLs in the browser, write code in the browser to validate URLs.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment

Comment: I want to pass regular expressions to a client.